# Facebook Like Button shifts entire page centering when shown in div

Tags: jquery, css, facebook-like, html

I am trying to center my facebook like button.  It is within a div that is shown/hidden based on menu items clicked.  When I click the li (news and updates) that shows that div (and hides the others), my entire page gets shifted when clicked.  Strangely enough, when I am "inspecting the element" in chrome, it does not shift.  You should be able to copy and paste code from the window and view html (top banner wont load).

Any obvious css mistakes?  Thanks in Advance

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Chef's Classic - Knock OUT 'Bout</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
div {
    display: block;
}
.tabs {
    text-align:center;
}
.tabs ul {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
    /* For IE, the outcast */
    zoom:1;
    *display: inline;
}
.tabs li {
    list-style:none;
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:center;  
}
.tabs a {
    padding:5px 10px;
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:#000000;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    text-decoration:none;
    width:150px;
    font-family: "Palatino Linotype", "Book Antiqua", Palatino, serif;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px; /* Saf3-4, iOS 1-3.2, Android ≤1.6 */
    -moz-border-radius: 10px; /* FF1-3.6 */
    border-radius: 10px; /* Opera 10.5, IE9, Saf5, Chrome, FF4, iOS 4, Android 2.1+ */
}

.tabs a:hover {
    background-color:#D7181E;
}

.tabs a.active {
    padding:5px 10px;
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:#666666;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-family: "Palatino Linotype", "Book Antiqua", Palatino, serif;
}

</style> </head>
  <body style="   background-color:#666666">
  <div id="fb-root"></div>  

    <div style="display:block; width: 800px; margin:0px auto; background-color:#FFFFFF; border-width: 50px 50px 50px 50px; -moz-border-image: url(images/main-border-oil-grey.png) 71 repeat; -webkit-border-image: url(images/main-border-oil-grey.png) 71 repeat; -o-border-image: url(images/main-border-oil-grey.png) 71 repeat; border-image: url(images/main-border-oil-grey.png) 71 repeat;">
      <!--banner-->
      <div style="text-align:center;"> 
        <img height="250" src="images/banner.jpg" alt="Chef's Classic Knock Out Bout" /> 
      </div>
      <!--links-->
      <div class="tabs" style="text-align:center">
        <ul>
          <li> <a href="#pages-about">About</a> </li>
          <li> <a href="#pages-facebook">News &amp; Updates</a> </li>
          <li> <a href="#pages-tickets">Tickets</a> </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!--pages-->
      <div id="pages-about" style="min-height:400px;">

      </div>
      <div id="pages-facebook" style="min-height:400px;">

        <div class="fb-like-box" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/Chefs-Classic-Knock-OUT-Bout/225835004169328"

          data-width="550" data-height="600" data-show-faces="false" data-border-color="#D7181E"

          data-stream="true" data-header="true"> </div>
        <!--<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fpages%2FChefs-Classic-Knock-OUT-Bout%2F225835004169328&amp;width=550&amp;height=427&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;show_faces=false&amp;border_color=%23D7181E&amp;stream=true&amp;header=true" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:550px; height:427px;" allowTransparency="true">
        </iframe>--> </div>
      <div id="pages-tickets" style="min-height:400px;">
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
  <script type="text/javascript">(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script> <script type="text/javascript">
// Wait until the DOM has loaded before querying the document
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.tabs ul').each(function(){
        // For each set of tabs, we want to keep track of
        // which tab is active and it's associated content
        var $active, $content, $links = $(this).find('a');

        // Use the first link as the initial active tab
        $active = $links.first().addClass('active');
        $content = $($active.attr('href'));

        // Hide the remaining content
        $links.not(':first').each(function () {
            $($(this).attr('href')).hide(); //assumes href contains div name
        });

        // Bind the click event handler
        $(this).on('click', 'a', function(e){
            // Make the old tab inactive.
            $active.removeClass('active');
            $content.hide();


            // Update the variables with the new link and content
            $active = $(this);
            $content = $($(this).attr('href'));

            // Make the tab active.
            $active.addClass('active');
            $content.show();

            // Prevent the anchor's default click action
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
});
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: One thing I noticed right away was the `.tabs ul` line `*display: inline;`.  Looks like you added an asterisk (*) on accident.

Comment: good catch, unfortunately isn't the aha I was looking for :), still does the funky monkey and shifts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the windows scroll bar showing and hiding. Once you have content in all your tabs this should not be an issue.

Comment: I actually do have stuff in all tabs, I just deleted everything out of them to bring the code down to show that facebook is affecting it.

Comment: Ahh I see what you are saying, okay, so essentially adding 'enough' data would make it always be there, or setting max-height, or a footer.

Comment: yes its annoying, its one area where IE worked quite well that the scroll bar was active or not active but always there. its a matter of opinion but as most pages require a scroll its quite nice to have it there all the time. I have often had clients complain about the jump, and to diagnose it is hard as people have the browsers at different sizes and find it hard to explain :-)